# How to manually start resizing via jquery-ui resizable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-resizable

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
$('#wrapper').mousemove(function(){
    $newContainer.trigger('resize');
})
```

It doesn't work and should not work.
There is any way to start resizing, not clicking on .ui-resizable-handle element?

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can resize an element on mousemove. But for that you can make a css class and after firing of that event you can simply add the class to that element. Or you can use margin, padding, height, width to resize.

```
    $('#wrapper').mousemove(function(){
        $newContainer.addClass('css_class_name');
    });

    or 

    $('#wrapper').mousemove(function(){
        $newContainer.height('200');//according to your need
        $newContainer.width('200');
    });
```